# Hide radio button icon but not text

Tags: android, radio-button, visibility

I need to hide a radio button's icon: something like setting it to invisible, but only the icon, not the text (`setInvisible` hides also the text). The icon should still take up space, so that the text is aligned with that of the other radio buttons. Also, the radio button (its text) should be clickable.

In other words, what I want is for the icon to be "transparent" (not visible), but otherwise "be there": be clickable, take up space.

I need to do this programmatically, not in XML.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a RadioButton with no Text, and to the left of it a TextView containing the RadioButtons description.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Good idea, but in my case it is difficult to apply, because I need to turn the button from "normal" to "no icon" and back

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**XML:**

```
<RadioButton
   android:paddingLeft="31dp"
   android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
```

**Java:**

```
RadioButton myButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio);
   myButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
   myButton.setPadding(31, 0, 0, 0);
```

setPadding() takes int values that represent Padding in Pixels,
see [Definition@Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) so adjust the Padding as required.

Comment: @MBennett Thanks. It works, except that `"31dp"` (a string) is not allowed as a first argument to `setPadding`. I have changed it to `(int) (31*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f`, so as to convert from 31dp to pixels. Maybe you want to change your answer accordingly. It turns out to be too narrow, maybe I'll have to play with the width. Or have I done the conversion wrong?

Comment: 34dp (converted to pixels) seems to work in Android 4.0. In 2.3 a slightly larger value is required

Comment: This works for me
`myButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);` where `myButton.setButtonDrawable(null);` did not thanks.

Comment: when I use 'android:button="@android:color/transparent"' ,while selecting radiobutton also ,selection is not visible

Comment: radio button circle should not be visible, at the same time, when I select tick mark should come -How to achieve this, any help

Answer (score 13):

set `android:button="@null"` will remove the default radio icon

```
<RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/rb1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:button="@null"
     android:text="Female" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Old post, but it might help someone.
Setting `android:button="@null"` didn't worked for me for older versions. The only way that I could hide the circle was setting this style to the `RadioButton`

```
<style name="Radio" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
  <item name="buttonCompat">@null</item> <!-- Key! -->
  <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide the circle button, there is needed just declare the following

```
<RadioButton
  app:buttonCompat="@null"
  android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For hiding default circle icon in radio button just add a single line:

```
android:button="@null"
```